# RecyclerView-How to know if there is 5 items to scroll?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I load data from internet and i'm doing pagination.

I use this code to load more data:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)&&loading==false&&postson==false){
                loading=true;
                lastitem+=20;
                loaddata(lastitem);

            }
        }


    });
```

But this only works when recycler view reachjes the bottom and i think this might confuse the user.
I want to load more data when 5 item left.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the item count of the layout Manager (make your layout manager global), probably linear layout manager then from there compare the two Like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        if (!isRequesting) {
            int visiblePicturePosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
            int totalItems = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount()
            if (totalItems - visiblePicturePosition <= 5) {

                //Do what you want here
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes it works great but do you know how to do that in nested scroll view?

Comment: I get to it now, but start using it and if you find a problem, Ask another question and Comment the question link here, So I may follow it. Also **Happy Coding!**